# Strongly typed vs Weakly typed

Tags: php, strong-typing, weakly-typed

I have recently been appointed as a Developer in a project which uses PHP backend. With previous experience in strongly typed languages like C#, it has been tough for me. In C#, it easier to:-

- Find all references
- Better debug experience
- Know what type of object to be expected

and many more...

I know the benefits of a weakly typed language like JavaScript which opens the possibility of a whole lot of things you can do with it. But when you have business logic with business objects, I would rather prefer a strongly typed language.

My real question is if you have something like this:-

```
public function saveEntity($externalId, $layer, $sign = null, $user= null, $pass = null) {
```

How am I supposed to know what $layer contains without having to read all of the lines of code before a call to this function? Is there a trick/gotcha in places like these where identifying the type of object is important?

Comment: I hope they added comments.

Comment: Use phpdocs to help knowing the type and content of each parameter

Comment: Also you can use a good ide like phpstorm to follow references and function usages (ctrl+click or ctrl+b I think)

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches.

You can use [phpdoc](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html) to annotate your methods and variables:

```
/**
 * @param int $externalID
 * @param Layer $layer
 * ...
 * @return boolean
 */
public function saveEntity($externalId, $layer, $sign = null, 
                           $user= null, $pass = null) { ... }
```

Or just write the type in the method declaration (requires PHP >= 7):

```
public function saveEntity(int $externalId, Layer $layer, $sign = null, 
                           $user= null, $pass = null): boolean { ... }
```

Or, preferably, use both.

Doing this consistently in your code gives you all you need while still reaping the benefits of a dynamic language. Your IDE can then do refactoring, find usages and issue warnings etc.

Comment: Using both is my preference and working very well also with team mates. IDEs like PHPStorm makes this very convenient.

Comment: Just use both, but make sure that they don't contradict each other.

Comment: What about when the object is serialized due to an API call. This JSON can change, right? Plus if you start modifying the object after serialization then it is hard to predict its state unless you look at everything that has been done to this object. In a strongly typed world, changes in JSON will force you to change your object type accordingly.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you are asking here, but there is a [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface that might do what you want.

Comment: My only argument is, how do you predict what an object contains at design time?